# Custom attribute with name "Field" doesn't compile on delphi

Tags: delphi, attributes, delphi-11-alexandria

In Delphi 11.3, I have created a custom attribute with name "Field" but it doesn't compile when I try to annotate it to a class field.

Here's the code:

```
  Field = class(TCustomAttribute)

  end;

  TUser = class
  private
    [Field()]
    FName: string;
  end;
```

and the error is

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(24): E2029 ':' expected but '(' found

Comment: Does the attribute really need to be named "Field"?

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Do you have the same problem if you rename the `TFieldAttribute` class to something else, or if you remove the parenthesis, ie `[Field]`? You don't need to use parenthesis unless your attribute class defines a constructor with parameters.

Comment: That being said, do be aware that the `Data.DB` unit defines a [`TFieldAttribute`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TFieldAttribute) type that is not an attribute class. Are you using `Data.DB` in the unit that is failing to compile?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In 11.3, it simply appears not to be possible to use `Field` as an attribute name. (But `Fiend` works.) Similarly, `Method` seems not possible (but `Metod` works). Apparently there are some undocumented or poorly documented restrictions here.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand sounds like a bug (compiler or documentation) that should be [reported to Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: RSP-42443

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand apparently Delphi doesn't accept attributes with class member names (`Field`, `Method`).

Comment: I'm gonna change the attribute name from `Field` to `Element` to get around this problem. Thank you guys.